# Implementing pause/resume function in Java game

Tags: java

I have managed to pause the game using `*running = !running`

But it's unable to unpause if this is used

And `thread.resume()` or `thread.wait()` doesn't work either to unpause it when 'P' is pressed

```
private volatile boolean running;
private Thread thread;

public static enum STATE {
    MENU,
    GAME,
};

public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;

public void init(){
    requestFocus();
}

private synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    init();

    while(running){
        /some codes
    }
    stop();
}

private void render(){

    if(State == STATE.GAME){
        p.render(g);
        c.render(g);

    }else if(State == STATE.MENU){
        menu.render(g);
    }

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(State == STATE.GAME){
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        p.setVelX(5);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        p.setVelX(-5);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p.setVelY(5);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        p.setVelY(-5);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !is_shooting){
        c.addEntity(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), tex, this));
        is_shooting = true;
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P){
```

**This line is to pause.**

```
        running = !running;
    }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        p.setVelX(0);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        p.setVelX(0);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p.setVelY(0);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        p.setVelY(0);
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        is_shooting = false;
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P){


// This line doesn't work.

        running = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have broken out of the loop, set running to true wont restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, as soon as `running` is set to false, your game thread exits (run() method returns).

```
public void run() {
    init();
    while(running){
        /some codes
    }
    stop();
}
```

Should be changed to something more like this:

```
public void run() {
    init();
    while(true){
        if(!running) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);  //1 second or something else
            continue;
        }
        //Game logic here
    }
    stop();
}
```

You will of course need to differentiate between running and paused, to be able to break out of this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Setting running = !runnning will just change the variable, you're not actually stopping anything unless you're using the variable in the game loop.

To pause the method, use `Thread.sleep()`or simply stop the thread, then start it again if you don't know how long you want to pause it for.